# When importing this simple SVG into Photoshop it doesn't show anything, why?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, svg, export, import

I'm trying to import this SVG, but for some reason it's not working.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="#FF5900">
<path d="M15.289 8.604c-1.138 0-2.204.071-3.271.142-2.844.213-5.618.711-8.391 1.422l2.418 2.773a37.323 37.323 0 015.547-.853c-.853 3.413-2.773 6.4-5.547 8.462v3.911c4.693-2.631 7.964-7.253 8.96-12.587.213-1.067.284-2.204.284-3.271zM28.231 10.169c-2.773-.711-5.547-1.209-8.391-1.422-1.067-.071-2.204-.142-3.271-.142 0 1.138.071 2.204.284 3.271.996 5.333 4.267 9.884 8.96 12.587v-3.911c-2.773-2.062-4.693-5.049-5.547-8.462 1.849.142 3.698.498 5.547.853l2.418-2.773zM14.436 24.533l2.987-3.413v-3.627h-2.987z"></path>
```

When I import this svg, nothing is showing in the photoshop at all.

But when I import this

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 39 34" id="f_icon_7f4d18e8">
    <path d="M0 17L9.75 0h19.5L39 17l-9.75 17H9.75L0 17z" fill="#141318"></path>
</svg>
```

this issue does not happen?

Why is that like that? Google Chrome has no issue displaying the SVG either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's missing the

> `</svg>`

closing tag.

Chrome is more forgiving than a graphics editor...

Comment: I actually wonder how I did not notice that.

Also, now that I look again, Google Chrome now reports with an error message, I don't think it used to do that before. But it displays it with the SVG which is fine.